# Will this design cause corrosion from a ground loop?

Tags: ground, grounding, ground-loop, corrosion

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiKCVZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The design is an undersea light.

- The connector provides the customer ground-line-neutral.
- The line and neutral are connected to an LED driver board.
- The green ground wire is connected to the ground plane of the driver board.
- The ground plane of the driver board is screwed to the first housing component with good contact
- A 3 inch ground wire is run to a second housing component which is isolated from the first by hard a nodize.
- Both housing components are wetted by seawater.

This was tested in fresh water for 3 months with no issues. But a prototype version with soft anodize started to corrode pretty quickly at high temperature.

1. Will the cause galvanic corrosion as-described?
2. Will this cause galvanic corrosion when (not if!) the anodize is damaged?
3. If the housing were not connected to the earth ground, what would be the purpose of the earth ground?

Comment: Draw a picture, don't use words.

Comment: Hi! There is an integrated schematic tool in the toolbar above the box where you write your question. The shortcut for it seems to be Ctrl+M.

Comment: Are you intending this design to be used without a GFCI or RCD? I doubt that you could but I need to ask. Are you the designer or the user?

Comment: Andy, I am the mechanical engineer / project engineer. We have only one EE on staff and he is not especially senior and I try not to leave him hung out to dry. I also feel like I should understand this issue better than I do as an ME.

Comment: Andy, yes, our documentation recommends a GFI. Edited to add schematic. It seems like a pretty slick tool for circuit diagrams, but my skills with it are shameful--sorry. I will clarify it again if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Although some pictures would be needed to determine a corrosion pattern and investigate the cause in deep, we could assume that:

1. Galvanic corrosion should be completely discarded. Low DC voltages (i.e. 3.3V, 5.0V) with respect to ground (sea water) would not be enough to cause a relevant corrosion thickness (less than 2 nm per month). As per [skb.com](https://www.skb.com/publication/2276284/P-11-43.pdf):

> An external field with 5V maximum voltage and an internal resistance
>   of 500 Ω would give a corrosion attack of about 2,600 μm in 100,000
>   years.

Comment: The discussion is about using AC power on a light in an aluminum housing in sea water, and whether the ground wire for the AC power circuit will contribute to corrosion.  That's AC, not DC.  That's 120V, not 5V.  That's milliohms of source impedance, not hundreds of ohms.